# How to delete a file only if the file exit in a given location in java?

Tags: java, delete-file

I want to code a java snippet to check a file with a specific name, if the file exists, delete the file and if not continue running the rest of the code. I tried following snippets to the test case to do this but it causes a null point exception if the file does not exist.

```
File deleteFile =new File((System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/file.txt"));
if(deleteFile.exists()) {
    deleteFile.delete();
}
```

```
File deleteFile =new File((System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/file.txt"));
if(deleteFile.isDirectory()) {
    deleteFile.delete();
}
```

But neither of them solves my problem. Since I work with version control I want to make sure there will be no build break from my codes.

Comment: `delete()` simply returns false if the file doesn't exist. If you're getting a null pointer exception then you have a null reference somewhere else. Please give us a [mre] with a complete code listing and the exact error message you're seeing.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of the NPE? Nothing here looks like it should produce such an error.

Comment: I'm using version control and about 20 peoples are working on the same branch. One of my codes had created a file in other's locals which creates errors. I fixed my original code and now I want to delete the existing file on others locals. thats why i need the snippet for delete a file only if it exists.

Comment: [ERROR] test_zipFiles  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/e/project-src/main/resources/user01/zipSource/testDirectory (No such file or directory)

Comment: Are you trying to commit code to _production_ in order to delete _project files_ that code from a previous commit erroneously created? Because that seems like the wrong approach; better to just have the others clean up their local branches. Or are you trying to create a simple, one-time-use tool to delete the files?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/file.txt"));
```

This method will return `true` if file exists and was deleted, else `false`

Comment: What's wrong with the OP's code? Why is this better?